# RSA: select $e$ given $n$ and $\varphi(n)$

Tags: rsa

I have a question for a course I am doing. In an RSA question, it asks "Is it possible to select $e$ in such a way that it coincides with the corresponding private key $d$? If it is possible, provide a value for such an $e$.

So, this is only part of the question (last part really).

$$n = 22499$$
$$\varphi(n) = 22200$$

How would I go about this? I am completley lost. I have, by luck come across an answer of $149$. $149^2 = 1 \pmod{22200}$. This is because $ed = 1 \pmod{\varphi(n)}$. Is there a method to calculate such a number? [$a^x = 1 \pmod{\varphi(n)}$]

Comment: $e=d\Rightarrow e^2\equiv 1 \pmod{\varphi(n)}$. Can you solve this equation? (given the factorization of $\varphi(n)$?)

Comment: I have no idea how to haha. What do you mean by "factorisation of φ(n)"?

Comment: "The factorization of $\phi(n)$"; $\phi(n)$ is an integer; the factorization of an integer is the (multi)set of primes that, when multiplied together, form that integer.  For example, the factorization of $22200 = 2 \times 2 \times 2 \times 3 \times 5 \times 5 \times 37$

Comment: Ah yes, prime factorisation, but how would this help me? IM fairly new to all this.

Comment: @ColonCapsDee, did you discuss "modular square roots" in any of your courses yet?

Comment: Nope, i dont think so. Ill try take a quick look around about it.

Comment: You can always use $e = \varphi(n) - 1$.

Comment: @Aleph another trivial solution would be $e=d=1$.

Comment: Another one is $\sqrt{\varphi(n)+1}$ (if integer).

Comment: Haha yes, i managed to come up with these solutions. However, the question was 10 marks and im wondering if that even is enough for the full marks. But thanks :)

Answer (score 5):

There are four different solutions, of which three have been identified as the "trivial solutions" in the comments to this question.

1. $e=d=1$ which is obviously fullfilling the condition that $1\cdot 1\equiv 1 \pmod{\varphi(n)}$ should hold.
2. $e=d=\varphi(n)-1$ which is fullfilling the condition that $(\varphi(n)-1)^2\equiv 1 \pmod{\varphi(n)}$ as $(\varphi(n)-1)^2=((\varphi(n))^2-2\varphi(n)+1) \bmod{\varphi(n)}=1$
3. $e=d=\sqrt{\varphi(n)+1}$ (if integer) which is also obviosuly true as $\sqrt{\varphi(n)+1}^2=(\varphi(n)+1)\bmod{\varphi(n)}=1$, this is the solution you stumbled across.
4. Use a full modular square root finding algorithm as documented as algorithm 3.44 in the *Handbook of Applied Cryptography* on page 102. [(PDF version)](http://cacr.uwaterloo.ca/hac/about/chap3.pdf) However this requires you to know the prime factorization of $\varphi(n)$ which may be infeasible to obtain for sufficiently large $n$.

Comment: I've posted this answer as a community wiki, as I do not feel my contribution to answering this question was large enough to warrent any reputation gains, especially since I only could bring the trivial solutions: "look the algorithm up" and "1" in.

Comment: I would rephrase "four different solutions" as "four different approaches" or something, because it could be (incorrectly) interpreted as meaning that there are four solutions for $e$.

Comment: @Aleph It's a community wiki answer so feel free to make any edits you see fitting and improving it.

Answer (score 1):

Factoring $\varphi(n) = 22200$, we get $22200 = 2^3 \cdot 3 \cdot 5^2 \cdot 37$.  The condition $d = e$ implies $e^2 \equiv 1 \pmod{\varphi(n)}$.  In turn, this yields $e \equiv \{\pm 1,\pm 3\} \pmod{2^3}$, $e \equiv \pm 1 \pmod{3}$, $e \equiv \pm 1 \pmod{5^2}$, and $e \equiv \pm 1 \pmod {37}$.  All possible solutions are then obtained through Chinese remaindering.  There are $4\cdot 2\cdot 2\cdot 2 = 32$ solutions: 1, 149, 1849, 1999, 3551, 3701, 5401, 5549, 5551, 5699, 7399, 7549, 9101, 9251, 10951, 11099, 11101, 11249, 12949, 13099, 14651, 14801, 16501, 16649, 16651, 16799, 18499, 18649, 20201, 20351, 22051, 22199.